# How do I resolve LNK2019 in a VS2008 solution that has multiple projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker

Yes, yet another LNK 2019 question but I haven't been able to find a solution to my specific problem.

Hope you can help with this as it is completely flummoxing me. This is my first go with multiple projects and C++ unit testing.

Background:

- Win32 console app
- Project A - main application (main.cpp, do_app.cpp, do_app.hpp)
- Project B - Boost unit test of Project A (do_test.cpp)
- Project B depends on Project A in Project Dependencies.
- Project A is compiled first in the build sequence.
- Project B includes files in Project A in Additional Include Dependencies.
- do_test.cpp includes do_app.hpp.

When I build the project, I get the following error:

```
do_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl dummy(void)" (?dummy@@YAHXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall AddTask_noTasksExistAtAll_dataFileCreated::test_method(void)" (?test_method@AddTask_noTasksExistAtAll_dataFileCreated@@QAEXXZ)
2>D:\Documents\Trader Rick\Projects\do\Debug\do_test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

`int dummy()` is a function prototyped in do_app.hpp and defined in do_app.cpp. It's called by do_test.cpp.

If I replace

```
#include "do_app.hpp"
```

with

```
#include "do_app.cpp"
```

then the problem disappears and the executable performs as expected.

Now clearly, the linker in building do_test.exe cannot see the do_app.obj file. My question is why not? I think I've set the Project properties correctly for Project B.

Any ideas guys?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK. Don't know this if this is an answer or a workaround.

When unit testing an executable, the Boost methodology itself creates another executable. You therefore have 2 executables in the same solution, which VS doesn't like.

- Remove your main entry point for the program under test from your solution i.e. remove `main.cpp` in my particular case.
- Move the code you want to test in your main entry point to a separate compilation unit. (From now on, let this code be called from `main.cpp` rather than actually be contained in it.)
- Build a static library from this code under test instead of an executable.
- Now you should be able to run Boost unit tests without a problem.